# Why are some .exe's that are found in Program Files also in the System32 folder?

Tags: windows-7, java

As a specific example, I was troubleshooting something related to javaws.exe (Java Web Start) and found it in two places:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaws.exe
```

and

```
C:\Windows\System32\javaws.exe
```

I'm guessing the Java installer put it in both folders.  Is it also in the System32 folder because C:\Windows\System32 is in the PATH?  Which means you can call `javaws` from a cmd shell without specifying the absolute path (is that correct?).

My background is mainly Linux, so just trying to understand Windows a little deeper.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually yes,

System32 is in the system path and you can call these apps (executables) in every where.

Comment: However, it's not recommended on newer versions of Windows.

Comment: I agree Randolph, You should not copy files in system32 manually, If an installer copies it, it generally has a good reason to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Some programs put them there so they can run at boot time, or run with other programs when started. System32 is the default system path in Windows.

> javaws.exe is a process by Sun Microsystems which gives functionality to this Internet protocol. Often works together with Internet Explorer.
>
> The javaw.exe command is identical to java.exe, except that with javaw.exe there is no associated console window. This implies you can't get it to display the version with -version, since there is no console to display it on. Use javaw.exe when you don't want a command prompt window to appear. The javaw.exe launcher will, however, display a dialog box with error information if a launch fails for some reason.

http://www.neuber.com/taskmanager/process/javaw.exe.html

http://www.processlibrary.com/directory/files/javaws/25654/